# Firemonkey setContentView

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I can't figure out how to set the main view / layout on Android via Delphi code.

I have the following layout file named 'activity_tv.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have the following strings file named 'strings.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello!</string>
</resources>
```

Both are added in the deployment section as `ProjectFile` with the correct output directory. Both are working properly and I can receive non-zero resource ids with the following code:

```
LayoutID := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getResources.getIdentifier(
  TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('tvlayout'),
  TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('layout'),
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.getPackageName()
);

StringID := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getResources.getIdentifier(
  TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('hello'),
  TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('string'),
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.getPackageName()
);
```

I'm trying to set the main activity's layout, but nothing happens. This is the code I'm trying:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CallInUIThread(SetMainLayout);
end;

procedure TForm1.SetMainLayout;
var
  LayoutID: Integer;
begin
  LayoutID := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getResources.getIdentifier(
    TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('tvlayout'),
    TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('layout'),
    TAndroidHelper.Activity.getPackageName()
  );

  TAndroidHelper.Activity.setContentView(LayoutID);
end;
```

That's the entire project. I do have a button on the form and tried to call `CallInUIThread(SetMainLayout)` from its Click handler, but the same thing happens: The button stays on the form and I don't see my view. I've tried moving the button around in case it was getting in the way.

I've tried inflating the layout myself, in two different ways. Both times I get (what I assume is) a valid View pointer back, and the app doesn't crash, but it doesn't do anything either:

```
//attempt one
inflater := TJLayoutInflater.JavaClass.from(TAndroidHelper.Context);
layoutView := inflater.inflate(LayoutID, nil);
TAndroidHelper.Activity.setContentView(layoutView);

//attempt two
InfObj := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
Inflater := TJLayoutInflater.Wrap((InfObj as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
layoutView := Inflater.inflate(LayoutID, nil);
TAndroidHelper.Activity.setContentView(layoutView);
```

I thought that maybe I had to add an activity to the AppManifest, but I repeated the following steps in Android Studio and everything worked fine:

1. Create an empty project with a main activity
2. Create a new layout file named activity_tv.xml containing the exact code from this question.
3. Edit strings.xml to include a "hello" string.
4. Change the call in the MainActivity class from `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_tv);`

For good measure, I created a completely new Delphi project to make sure I didn't miss anything. The only Delphi code file is here:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  FMX.Forms, Androidapi.Helpers, FMX.Helpers.Android;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure SetMainLayout;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CallInUIThread(SetMainLayout);
end;

procedure TForm1.SetMainLayout;
var
  LayoutID: Integer;
begin
  LayoutID := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getResources.getIdentifier(
    TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('activity_tv'),
    TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('layout'),
    TAndroidHelper.Activity.getPackageName()
  );

  TAndroidHelper.Activity.setContentView(LayoutID);
end;

end.
```

How do I get `setContentView` to work in Delphi?

Version of Delphi:

```
Embarcadero® Delphi 10 Seattle Version 23.0.20618.2753
```

Comment: FMX implements its own Window rendering, so very likely it will interfere with your attempt to use native layouts. But, before that there is another issue. in Delphi Seattle FMX UI runs on different thread from Android UI thread. Calling UI methods outside Android UI thread will fail. You have to use TAndroidHelper.Activity.runOnUiThread and setContentView from that.

Comment: The first thing you note is what I'm worried about. But there must be a way? Why even wrap all the UI classes if I can't use them? But I did call it on the UI thread with `CallInUIThread`. I think that will run it on the Android UI thread, but I can try with `runOnUiThread`.

Comment: I missed that. Well, it seems that FMX rendering is to blame then. Check https://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiandroid/ maybe you will find answer there.

Comment: Thanks! I'll took a look in a few hours. I have to go run some errands.

Comment: try to look implementation of native control (like Tedit) in https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe. to resume you can not put in the windows any android visual control as delphi paint itself the windows, but what you can do is to put in top of your delphi windows ANOTHER windows with your visual controm inside (on you position well this video). look how it's done with TALEdit as sample

Comment: take a look at this https://www.turbococoa.com/guide.html